# Set Resolution above 1200dpi with WIA

Tags: c#, resolution, wia, epson

I need to scan an image using the Scanner Epson Perfection V550 Photo in 3200dpi. I'm using C#, Visual Studio and [this code](http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/11/17/playing-with-the-scanner-with-wia-and-c/) to generate a program using WIA, without any dialog box, that could just save the image to some file in my computer.

So by changing the scanResolutionDPI to over 1200 (e.g. 1400), I got an error in the prop.set_Value line, because it exceeds the WIA resolution range (50dpi-1200dpi)

The problem is that I believe that WIA would take the device properties via the scanner driver, and the maximum effective resolution for this scanner is 6400dpi as it says in [this manual](https://files.support.epson.com/docid/cpd3/cpd39283.pdf).

So, why WIA takes this resolution range and not the true scanner's range? How could I get over this problem? Can I change something in the scanner's driver to "trick" WIA? Is it really possible to scan over 1200dpi using WIA?

Comment: Hmm, seems unlikely.  Visit Epson to obtain the latest driver for this scanner.  And do keep in mind that you are generating a monster bitmap.  At 6400 dpi, one page takes over 14 gigabytes in memory.  That's not practical.

Comment: What seems unlikely? I downloaded the latest driver, it doesn't work. And yeah, it would be really big, but actually it's 3200 dpi and I want to scan just a 70mmx18mm document, so the file is about 100Mb< :)